# How to store the numbers for the 2048 game

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2048

I have been trying to implement the game 2048.

I can add numbers in random positions of the grid and I can also slide them to a side, as that is what the `console.log` shows me.

But somehow I am not able to maintain that effect of a slide. Whenever I call `key` again, the rows are like there was no effect of the previous slides.

```
function slide(row) {
  arr = row.filter(e => e);
  let missing = 4 - arr.length;
  let zeros = Array(missing).fill(0);
  arr = arr.concat(zeros);
  console.log(arr);
  return arr;
}

function key() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    slide(grid[i]);
  }
  addNumber();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm sorry, but I honestly have no idea what your question is trying to ask. Very little of your text makes any sense, and your code doesn't help at all. Please have a read of the [ask] section of the [help] and then **edit** your question

Comment: Is there any more code involved that you could share?

Comment: yeah, I am a newbie and trying to use StackOverflow. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not modify the `row` that the function receives as argument. Instead you create a new array, which you return. But then the caller does not process the return value.

Instead of:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    slide(grid[i])
}
```

do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    grid[i] = slide(grid[i])
}
```

Now your grid will actually stay in sync with what the `slide` function does.